# Как сделать из двух массивов . Обьект с обьектами

Tags: javascript

Как сделать из двух масиивов . Обьект с обьектами такого вида ?
Дано два массива.

```
let arr1 = ['Scott', 'Esh' , 'Mike'];

let arr2 = ['Malk', 'Martin' , 'Grant'];
```

Сделать обьект такого вида .

```
let all = {

    0:{
        name:Scott,
        surname:Malk,
    }

    1:{
        name:Esh,
        surname:Martin,
    }

    2:{
        name:Mike,
        surname:Grant,
    }   
};
```

Comment: Про циклы вы что-то уже слышали?

Comment: Да слышал , немогу найти примера и как это сделать .

Comment: Найти примера цикла? В любой книжке для новичков, в любой документации   https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for    ....  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Comment: Найти пример , который я описал выше .  Получилось только найти как сделать масиив внутри котрого обьекты с использованием map , а тут немного по другому. Я понимаю если большой опыт , эта задача может оказаатся пустяком , но все же )

Answer (score 1):

Есть объект `obj`

- Берём обычный цикл `for` (не `for...in` и не `for...of`)
- Организовываем цикл со счётчиком от 0 до длины массива (**любого** из представленных)
- На каждой итерации в объект с ключом i (т.е. `obj[i]`) кладём объект такого типа:

  ```
  {
    name: XXX
    surname: YYY
  }
  ```

  где XXX - значение из массива `arr1` по ключу `i`, а YYY - значение из массива `arr2` по ключу `i`

Comment: Спасибо большое, у меня получилось !

Comment: Отлично! Галочку слева от ответа тык!

Answer (score 0):

Можно Вот так это сделать:

```js
const arr1 = ['Scott', 'Esh', 'Mike'];

const arr2 = ['Malk', 'Martin', 'Grant'];

function create_obj(arr1, arr2) {

  if (arr1.length != arr2.length)
    return "Длина массивов не совпадает...";

  const result = {};

  for (let i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; ++i) {

    let obj = {};
    obj['name'] = arr1[i];
    obj['surname'] = arr2[i];

    result[i] = obj;
  }

  return result;
}


console.log(create_obj(arr1, arr2));
```